# jquery conflict between two codes

Tags: jquery, conflict

i have a problem between two jquery codes

first code helps upload image and second: registration form data return

first:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var btnUpload = jQuery('#avatar');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'process/pic.php',
        name: 'avatar',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
            if (! (ext && /^(jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(ext))){

                // extension is not allowed
                showNotification({type : "information", message: 'Tikai *.jpg un *.jpeg formats.'});
                return false;
            }
            showNotification({type : "information", message: '<img src="img/loader.gif" />'});
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            if(response){
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and two:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#reg').submit(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery('#reg').attr('action'),
            data: jQuery('#reg').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                    showNotification({type : "warning", message: data});
                }else{
                    location.reload(true);
                }               
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

first code works just fine, but second won't work while delete the first code. Why?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: what exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: there is no error to read. Just jquery function ho without page relode show error from submited form, but in this situation form posting me to the action file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the two function in one jQuery(function(){}) like this:

```
jQuery(function(){

//the 1st function 
var btnUpload = jQuery('#avatar');
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action: 'process/pic.php',
    name: 'avatar',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
        if (! (ext && /^(jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(ext))){

            // extension is not allowed
            showNotification({type : "information", message: 'Tikai *.jpg un *.jpeg formāts.'});
            return false;
        }
        showNotification({type : "information", message: '<img src="img/loader.gif" />'});
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
        if(response){
            location.reload(true);
        }
    }
});

 //the 2nd function 

 jQuery('#reg').submit(function() { jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", url: jQuery('#reg').attr('action'), data: jQuery('#reg').serialize(), success: function(data) { if(data){ showNotification({type : "warning", message: data}); }else{ location.reload(true); }
} }); return false; }); 

                });
```

Comment: Jap and it does not change anything